# Rewind method in PHP SplPriorityQueue does not move iterator to the start of the queue

Tags: php

According to the PHP documentation for SplPriorityQueue, the "rewind" method rewinds the iterator back to the start of the queue. [Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splpriorityqueue.php) is the link to the documentation in question. From what I am seeing though, "rewind" doesn't accomplish the above. The way I am testing it is as follows:

```
$testQueue = new Stdlib\SplPriorityQueue();

$testQueue ->insert("Element 1", 3);
$testQueue ->insert("Element 2", 2);
$testQueue ->insert("Element 3", 1);

$testQueue ->next();
$testQueue ->next();
$testQueue ->rewind();
$currentNode = $testQueue ->current();
```

At that point $currentNode should be "Element 1", because that is the start of the queue. However, the value of $currentNode is "Element 3" instead.

My question(s) is, how exactly does "rewind" work and why does it not go to the start of the queue in the code example of above?